# google maps doesnt center my company's profile tag in iframe

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

I have added google maps to my website's contact page. but company's profile tag doesnt get centered in iframe. how can I fix this?

[image: google maps in my page]

here is the code I copied from google

```
<iframe width="790" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=rotasist+yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.005322,29.01218&amp;sspn=0.575166,1.352692&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=rotasist+yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=40.995204,29.099564&amp;spn=0.008988,0.021136&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=3028905870531188654&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=rotasist+yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.005322,29.01218&amp;sspn=0.575166,1.352692&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=rotasist+yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=40.995204,29.099564&amp;spn=0.008988,0.021136&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=3028905870531188654" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<iframe width="790" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=rotasist+yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.005322,29.01218&amp;sspn=0.575166,1.352692&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=rotasist+yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=41.007,29.099564&amp;spn=0.008988,0.021136&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=3028905870531188654&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=rotasist+yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.005322,29.01218&amp;sspn=0.575166,1.352692&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=rotasist+yaz%C4%B1l%C4%B1m&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=40.995204,29.099564&amp;spn=0.008988,0.021136&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;cid=3028905870531188654" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

I adjusted one of the lat/lon params (sent as ll) so that it would push the point closer to the lower border of the map, and show more of the popup window. In short, the param

```
ll=40.995204,29.099564
```

became

```
ll=41.007,29.099564
```

If thats still not good enough, you can adjust that ll param until you get it just where you want it.